# Visio 2007's UML feature: what methodology is this supporting?

Tags: modeling, visio, uml, methodology

I am attempting to depict a system under development in UML using Visio 2007.

Most examples of UML diagrams you find on the Web are fairly straightforward, particularly the class diagrams.  But in Visio you find lots of additional entities:  exception objects, component objects, lots and lots of stereotypes, relationships between entities, support for multiple languages (including pseudocode) and a model hierarchy viewer (that it is impossible to move things around in, but I digress).

What's got me curious is:  there's more going on here than simply drawing diagrams.  A lot of the information you can enter and the cross-references you can build are leading toward an actual workable model, possibly for use in code generation.  But I haven't been able to find what vision of modeling is being implemented, or what methodology this supports.

Whose ideas does this implementation support?  What system modeling methodology is this engineered for?  Are there any resources available?

Comment: Hi Ann ... I whole heartedly support that observation.  What's needed (imho) is a relaxed mode to let things get done (creative).  UML per se is too bureaucratic in the formal application.  Lamentably I could never get any hard-core UML-philes to consider that (they kept telling me use "profiles").

Comment: A suggestion though for the UML powers out there -- Make some tools that generate these very: "information you can enter and the cross-references you can build are leading toward an actual workable model, possibly for use in code generation", Ann talks about.  Yea?

Comment: IMHO Visio isn't an appropriate tool for UML modelling. Somehow Visio just supports drawing UML diagrams up to some point. A 'real' UML model has much more information than Visio is even able to keep tracked. My suggestion is to use a real UML modelling tool like Enterprise Architect: http://www.sparxsystems.com.au/